# Allowing users to upload images they want on the product at checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, image

With the Magento site being built, users need to be able to upload their selected images for graphics on the product.

I need to be able to offer, on checkout, an upload option which they can select how many images to upload and leave information. These images then need to go into a folder relating to the order ID so the client can go to that folder for the images.

Answer (score 1):

Magento has a very neat feature for that.
When adding a product, go to the custom options tab (it's usually the last one) and select "add new option".
From the "input type" drop-down, select "file" and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thanks for taken the time to answer. The only issue with this is the custom options allow you to upload the image from within product rather checkout as asked above.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realized you needed it on the checkout page.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having an issue with the Upload feature on Magento custom options. I'm not able to find images after customer uploads. It nowhere to be found when I check Magento backend and my FTP account. I've checked all folders in my /media directory and can't find anything